# What is the difference between Cloud-Init and Autoinstall?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init, preseed, devops, debconf

So I have been trying to essentially install Nixos from [the official site](https://nixos.org/download.html) with a Cloud-Init for Ubuntu Server 22.04. I want to really understand how to install packages that I potentially might have to compile or other ways of installing packages like with Curl or Wget within in the `user-data.yaml` file.

So far I have a `user-data.yaml` in which I am trying to use `runcmd:` to install Nox via the recommended way from there site.

My whole config is below and at the bottom is the `runcmd:` which I just can't get to install. The whole file looks like this.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_GB.UTF-8
  refresh-installer:
    update: true
  keyboard:
    layout: "gb"
  apt:
    geoip: true
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      match:
        size: largest
  packages:
    - libreoffice
    - sway
    - i3
    - kitty
  snaps:
    - name: firefox
  timezone: geoip
  manage_resolv_conf: true
  resolv_conf:
    nameservers:
      - 1.1.1.3
      - 8.8.8.8
  updates: all
  runcmd:
    - [mkdir, -m, 0755, /nix]
    - [chown, ubuntu, /nix]
    - [wget, "https://nixos.org/nix/install"]
    - [bash, install, --daemon]
```

If you run the installer via the command line you get prompt if you want to make the dir '/nix' hence the command for it. I'm at my wits end!

I have tried for the past 7 hours to get this package manager installed so I can install Wayland which would be a lot easier to install from here than installing it from source if I was to use RunCmd: the whole time.

Which from what I understand is the way to run bash commands

So far I have tried:

- Puting it to root so no `\s\s` before the `runcmd:` keyword
- Trying the commands in quotes like `"sh -c 'curl ....'"`
- Puting it in brackets like `[sh, -c, curl, "https://nixos.org/down.../install", |, bash]
- Other configuration of it in brackets like `[bash, -c, 'curl "https://nixos.org/down.../install" | bash'] *So many configurations!!
- Gone onto GitHub and search for examples of other people using `runcmd:`
- Following a DigitalOcean guide on Cloud-Init with `runcmd:` examples
- Read the reference for Cloud-init
- Read the reference for Autoinstall
- read the reference for Curtin

And I just don't know what to do next...

I'm using Qemu to test these configs with an Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Server ISO.

How do I just install stuff from a setup file that has an install script from the web?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with the same thing for hours!

Here's what seems to work (at least for me), so try this;

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
   version: 1
   ...
   user-data:
      runcmd:
        - mkdir -m 0755 /nix
        - chown ubuntu /nix
        - wget "https://nixos.org/nix/install"
        - bash install --daemon
```

Not sure about the brackets. My command worked without them so try that first for better readability.

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#user-data

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between Cloud-Init and Autoinstall?

Subiquity uses cloud-init, and it does so by overloading the cloud-init's config file with its own custom keys. This is why subiquity's docs (confusingly) call it a "cloud-config" - it is a cloud-config in the same way that most YAML files that start with `#cloud-config` are valid cloud-configs: undefined keys are ignored by cloud-init.

**Cloud-init doesn't use the autoinstall key to configure anything**, as described in the docs of both [cloud-init](https://canonical-cloud-init.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/reference/faq.html#autoinstall-preruncmd-postruncmd) and the [subiquity autoinstaller](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall).

> My whole config is below and at the bottom is the runcmd: which I just can't get to install.

Maybe someone else might be able to help with subiquity in more detail, but a glance at [subiquity's jsonschema](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-schema), it looks like you're trying to use keys that aren't valid for the autoinstaller. I don't see `runcmd` in the jsonschema.

> How do I just install stuff from a setup file that has an install script from the web?

I would recommend clarifying what, exactly, you're trying to ask.